# firestore cloud function, way to delete chat messages

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I`m studying cloud function right now and I saw this sample code

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Max number of lines of the chat history.
const MAX_LOG_COUNT = 5;

// Removes siblings of the node that element that triggered the function 
if there are more than MAX_LOG_COUNT.
// In this example we'll keep the max number of chat message history to 
MAX_LOG_COUNT.
exports.truncate = 
functions.database.ref('/chat/{messageid}').onWrite(async (change) => {
const parentRef = change.after.ref.parent;
const snapshot = await parentRef.once('value');
if (snapshot.numChildren() >= MAX_LOG_COUNT) {
let childCount = 0;
const updates = {};
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
  if (++childCount <= snapshot.numChildren() - MAX_LOG_COUNT) {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  }
});
// Update the parent. This effectively removes the extra children.
return parentRef.update(updates);
}
return null;
});
```

how do I convert this to Firestore version from RTDB? 
thank you

Comment: Please share mor information with us, like the source of the sample code, what are you trying to do, and what did you already tried

Comment: @Christian Gonzalez The above code is the sample firebase cloud function code which is I saw before 1hours ago, and I want to do it in Firestore Version. The code above is for realtime-database

Comment: @Christian Gonzalez asked for what you already tried to do. Stackoverflow is not a source for free code on request